# Understanding display:table-cell; functioning

Tags: css, css-tables

Please note that I am not trying to resolve any specific issue, **but trying to understand**  what's causing this issue.

I have set the `width`, `height` and `display` of some divs, but the height/width settings are not being honored. The text is also being pushed downward.

http://jsfiddle.net/k7esv/

[image]

1) Why does it push the text downward when `height` is set in table-row then BUT when `height` is removed, it places text at the top?

2) Why are the width/height settings not honored?

3) Why doesn't setting the `margin` property have any effect on them either?

http://jsfiddle.net/k7esv/1/

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but just to clarify for others: `display: table-cell` simulates the behaviour of a real table's cell (all cells have equal height, content cannot escape its container/the cell, and cells do not have margins but they can have padding and borders). Also, any `float` applied to `display: table-cell` elements cancels the effects of table-cell.

Answer (score 14):

1) This seems to be a rendering issue specific to Firefox. Setting the `vertical-align` property on the divs fixes it. `top`, `middle`, or `bottom` all seem to work. I don't understand myself what FF is doing when there is a `height` but no `vertical-align` set; it might be a bug.

2) The width and height are honored, but they are subject to table sizing rules. When a table does not have enough room to give each of the cells the width they have specified, it will give more room to cells that have more content. This is what was happening with your example. If you look at my example below, you will see that when the parent element is wider than the sum total of the table cells' widths, the cells respect the width. The height should always work (except in the case of the FF rendering issue I mentioned above).

3) Table cells don't have margins. Use border-spacing and display:table on a parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/chad/k7esv/3/

Comment: I updated my answer and my fiddle to address your first question. What you were seeing doesn't happen in WebKit, so I didn't see it at first.

Answer (score 4):

I will just add (seeing as it seems to have been missed) that setting the heights on individual table cells in a table row can be pointless, as all cells in the same table row will become the same height as the tallest cell in said row.

Having said that, heights may want to be added for when dynamic content is served to different cells, meaning their heights fluctuate. It may be that you want to set a particular cell to never be less than height X, which will only come in to effect when another certain cell has less content.

Comment: I had a weird cell displaying with padding I couldn't explain...I COULD NOT figure it out. After I read your reply, I had a "duh" moment and went back to discover a bottom margin on another element that was causing it. THANKS!