# IE8 background-color hiding borders

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, border, background-color

I am trying to add borders to navigation items. The background color is grey, and three of the borders are a lighter grey. The right border is black. On IE8, none of the borders show.

Here is how the `<li>` look in IE9:
[image]

Here is how they look on IE8:
[image]

And when I remove the `background-color` attribute, this is what shows up on IE8:
[image]

It seems like the background color is obscuring the borders. How can I fix this?

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="mainMenu">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
.mainMenu > li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #363636;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-left: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#363636 50%, #000 50%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#363636 50%, #000 50%); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#363636 50%, #000 50%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#363636 50%, #000 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#363636 50%, #000 50%);
}
```

EDITED: I mistakenly had a `div` instead of an `ul` surrounding my list items. On IE8 with the list items in an `ul`, this problem shows up.

Comment: Well I'm going to take a wild guess, your html is invalid, LI should be in an UL

Comment: Whoops- I am using the correct HTML in my webpage. I just copied it wrong into this question.

Comment: ... /* There is also a background gradient */  What do you mean ? Your question is of incomplete context ? If you don't provide FULL .css AND HTML context, it will be hard to help.

Comment: I added in the code for the background gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display: table-cell is your culprit. There is a [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442999/understanding-displaytable-cell-functioning) here about how the display: table-cell works and some of its idiosyncrasies. However, even if you take their great fiddle example and add a border to their "cells" you will find they suffer from the same problem you are having.

If you want to fix your issue I would advise going for a float:left style layout. You can handle the border duplication problem with something along these lines:

```
.mainMenu {
   list-style-type :none;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
.mainMenu > li {

    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: #363636;
    border-top: 10px solid #666;

    border-right: 10px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #666;
    /* There is also a background gradient */
}

.mainMenu > li:first-child {
  border-left: 10px solid #666;
}
```

I exaggerated the border size just for visual clarity. [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bUbLR/)
You will probably also want to make sure to clear the float shortly after your list items as well to ensure that it does not have any other side effects on your layout.