# How table-cell width with percentage value works?

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

I think it's better illustrated...

Assume our HTML:

```
<div>What the hack ?</div>
```

And our CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: pink;
}
```

You'll notice that the `<div>`'s width is behaving like a floating element: it's as large as its content instead of stretching to both sides.

Now start decrementing the width and suddenly you'll see the `<div>` growing.

Here's a interactive demo:

http://dabblet.com/gist/9891801

Why is that ? How does it work ?

Comment: If you remove display: table-cell the css works good for me

Comment: With or without `table-layout: fixed`? That changes everything when you want to set widths as there are 2 different algorithms: fit to content or - try to - obey to author (you). But your question may be related to [anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) (a cell has a parent row and a parent table; if not they'll come from nowhere).

Comment: Hm didn't know about `table-layout` I'm looking into it right now, thank you @FelipeAls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Math:

table-cell's width on 100% means that you have a table with a single cell per row. The known width - in your case - is the width of the text (89px).

If we put table-cell's width at 50%, that means the cell is wider as half of the whole table's width. We double the known width going to 178px.

Conclusion, the end width will be 100 / {table-cell's width} * {element's offsetWidth}

Why this happens is explained with the already posted link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `display: table-cell;` property ??

If you removed the div works good!

But If you want an explication just see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442999/understanding-displaytable-cell-functioning)

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer my question. I'm not asking for help to develop a layout, I'm asking why is that that a smaller percentage width make an element wider when it's being display as `table-cell`. i.e. how percentage values are calculated in this scenario.

Comment: Your link is relevant but still doesn't quite explain why this happen. I'm reading further anyway. Thanks.

Comment: No problem!! Glad for helping