# CSS: How to Apply Variable Widths Depending On Number of Siblings

Tags: css, dynamic, flexbox

I have a container element that might include either one or two sibling children. When there is only one child, I want it to be 100% the width of the parent. When there are two children, I want each to be 50% of the width of the parent. (And if I had three, I'd like each to be 33% width, etc.)

Is there a way to accomplish this with a pure CSS solution, or would I have to use Javascript to detect the number of elements, and style them accordingly?

The DOM structure could look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element1"></div>
</div>
```

or like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element1"></div>
     <div class="element2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to experiment on: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx3ae/

Comment: Post the code you have already tried?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle or what you've tried thus far? These things go way quicker with a code example.

Comment: [Use `display:table-cell`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442999/understanding-displaytable-cell-functioning)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mx3ae/ Have fun!

Comment: I believe this is a legit question with several viable responses, and edited it accordingly, to sharpen the question.

Answer (score 3):

The approach to this question depends on what browsers you have to support. If you need to support older browsers, you may need a hack like `display: table-cell`, or a javascript approach. Either way, it's harder than it should be.

But if you can use modern, evergreen browsers, the new CSS Flexbox specification makes this problem trivial. To use it in this case, you'd simply set `display: flex;` on the `.container` element. Then, because you want the internal elements to expand to consume any available space, you'd use the `flex-grow` property. In my example, I've set `flex-grow: 1;` so that they all take up the same amount of the remaining space, but you can use various values so that they vary in how much of the remaining space they consume. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mx3ae/3/).

That's just the beginning with Flexbox. You can allocate space dynamically, re-order display of your elements, and much more. I recommend Chris Coyier's ['Complete Guide to Flexbox'](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as your daily reference, although you may want to search for some tutorials as well.

EDIT: I shouldn't necessarily call `display: table-cell` a hack. It actually works pretty well, and is a use that the spec intends. Do try it if you need to dynamically allocate space for older browsers, or even if Flexbox doesn't give you *quite* what you want.

Comment: Great answer sadly it needs to be back to ie8, so script is going to be the only solution

Comment: `display: table-cell` should be supported on old IE. Give that a try.